# Cómo detectar si una línea de arrays coincide o no

Tags: javascript, array, bucles

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
//NÚMEROS ALEATORIOS PARA CREAR CARTÓN BINGO
function randoms(){
    var number1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    var number2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    var number3 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);       
    {
        return  number1, number2, number3
    };
 };   

//FACTORY FUNCTIONS PARA CREAR CARTÓN.
function NumerosCarton(){
    return {
        numero1 : randoms(), numero2 : randoms(), numero3 : randoms(),

    };
};

//CARTON CREADO
var numero = 5
carton = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= numero ; i++) {
    carton1 = {...NumerosCarton()};
    carton.push(carton1)
}

let cartonBingo = [];
let carton2 = carton.map(item => item.numero1);//NUMERO 1
let carton3 = carton.map(item => item.numero2);//NUMERO 2
let carton4 = carton.map(item => item.numero3);//NUMERO 3

cartonBingo.push(carton2,carton3,carton4)

var res1 = cartonBingo[0].every(function(element) {return typeof element === 'number';});
var res2 = cartonBingo[1].every(function(element) {return typeof element === 'number';});
var res3 = cartonBingo[2].every(function(element) {return typeof element === 'number';});


//NUMEROS BOMBO SIN REPETICIONES
    let numeros = []
    for (let randomNumber = 1; randomNumber < 20; randomNumber++) {  
        let random =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
        if(numeros.indexOf(random) == -1){
            numeros.push(random)
        } else {            
            randomNumber--
        }       
    }

//COINCIDENCIA ENTRE NÚMERO BOMBO Y CARTÓN BINGO
function vueltas() {       
alert('NÚMERO BOMBO ES = '+JSON.stringify(numeros[0]));
for (let r = 0; r < cartonBingo.length; r++) {    
    for (let c = 0; c < cartonBingo[r].length; c++) {    
        if(cartonBingo[r][c] === numeros[0]){           
            alert('COINCIDE!!!')            
            cartonBingo[r][c] = 'X'            
            alert('CARTÓN BINGO = ' + JSON.stringify(cartonBingo)) 
        } else {          
            alert('no coincide...')
        }       
    }   
}


numeros.splice(0,1);
alert('BOMBO RESTANTE = ' + JSON.stringify(numeros));
alert('CARTÓN BINGO = ' + JSON.stringify(cartonBingo))

alert('LINEA 1 = ' + JSON.stringify(cartonBingo[0]));
alert('LINEA 2 = ' + JSON.stringify(cartonBingo[1]));
alert('LINEA 3 = ' + JSON.stringify(cartonBingo[2]));

if(!res1){
    alert('línea!!');

}
if(!res2){
    alert('línea!!');
}

if(!res3){
    alert('línea!!');
}

vueltas();    
}
vueltas();
```

Lo que intento hacer es un Bingo, en el cual tengo un cartón aleatorio de 15 números con 3 líneas. Mi idea es sacar un número del bombo y que coincida con el cartón; si coincide, se tacha con una "X". Sin embargo, no logro que al tachar una línea completa de números me cante "LÍNEA" y que deje de sacar números del bombo al estar vacío(al comparar me sale UNDEFINED), lo intento con el método .every() para ir comparando si hay coincidencia y no hay caso (todo esto que vaya apareciendo en scripts)...  En qué puedo estar fallando? Si alguien sabe algo, estaré agradecido... Gracias a todos.

Comment: que tal si investigas [Creación de un cartón de bingo con espacios en negro y números aleatorios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/244169/creaci%c3%b3n-de-un-cart%c3%b3n-de-bingo-con-espacios-en-negro-y-n%c3%bameros-aleatorios) , Mauricio dio una excelente respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias @JackNavaRow, es bastante completo la verdad... aunque necesito algo más simple, estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y asimilar mejor los conceptos, sigo buscando, pero no puedo encontrar la solución más idónea... No sé si fallo en la manera que hago el cartón, o la comparación con el método .every()

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que la forma de resolver esto es:

- Iterando primero los números random,
- por cada número random cada línea y
- por cada línea cada número del cartón.

Es decir, 3 `for` anidados. Para hacerlo de la forma mas eficiente posible, porque son muchas iteraciones, yo eliminaría del array original del cartón las coincidencias, así cada iteración es siempre menor.

En principio en tu código siempre comparas con un solo número (`numeros[0]`) osea que sobre `vueltas()` deberías hacer un for mas cambiando de número. En fin, yo lo cambiaría de esta forma:

```js
//NÚMEROS ALEATORIOS PARA CREAR CARTÓN BINGO
function randoms() {
    var number1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    var number2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    var number3 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    {
        return number1, number2, number3
    };
};

//FACTORY FUNCTIONS PARA CREAR CARTÓN.
function NumerosCarton() {
    return {
        numero1: randoms(), numero2: randoms(), numero3: randoms(),

    };
};

//CARTON CREADO
var numero = 5
carton = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= numero; i++) {
    carton1 = { ...NumerosCarton() };
    carton.push(carton1)
}

let cartonBingo = [];
let carton2 = carton.map(item => item.numero1);//NUMERO 1
let carton3 = carton.map(item => item.numero2);//NUMERO 2
let carton4 = carton.map(item => item.numero3);//NUMERO 3

cartonBingo.push(carton2, carton3, carton4)

var res1 = cartonBingo[0].every(function (element) { return typeof element === 'number'; });
var res2 = cartonBingo[1].every(function (element) { return typeof element === 'number'; });
var res3 = cartonBingo[2].every(function (element) { return typeof element === 'number'; });

//NUMEROS BOMBO SIN REPETICIONES
let numeros = []
for (let randomNumber = 1; randomNumber < 20; randomNumber++) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    if (numeros.indexOf(random) == -1) {
        numeros.push(random)
    } else {
        randomNumber--
    }
}

const cartonOriginal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cartonBingo));

numeros.forEach(numero => {
    
     for(let linea = 0; linea<cartonBingo.length; linea++){
         for(let numeroCarton = 0; numeroCarton<cartonBingo[linea].length; numeroCarton++){            
                if(numero === cartonBingo[linea][numeroCarton]){
                    cartonBingo[linea].splice(numeroCarton,1);
                    if(!cartonBingo[linea].length){

                        console.log(`linea ${linea + 1 } coincidente`);
                        console.log(cartonOriginal[linea]);
                        cartonBingo.splice(linea,1);

                        if(!cartonBingo.length){
                            console.log("bingo!!!");
                            break;
                        }
                        linea = 0;
                    }                                       
                }
        }
     }

});
```

Comment: Gracias @Emeeus... Sin embargo, no es lo que busco, he intentado jugar con tu código y con el que tengo, pero no me sale... Mi idea es que vaya sacando un número del bombo y los vaya revisando uno por uno en el cartón del bingo que son 15 números con 3 filas de 5 números cada uno; si hay coincidencia, lo tacha con una "x", hasta que una de las 3 filas  esté tachada por completa y diga "línea ", y que siga tachando el resto de las filas hasta que cante "Bingo!!".. lo he intentado con loop anidado, y tampoco, no lo puedo conseguir(espero haberme explicado bien)... De todas formas, gracias.

Comment: Reemplazar los números con X no es lo más óptimo, pero si necesitas hacelo así, no es difícil adaptar el código, osea los for tienen que estar hagas lo que hagas.

Comment: Ya casi lo he logrado, diría que no estaba usando y/o escribiendo  el método. every() de la manera correcta;  ahora sólo me falta que al tachar una de las 3 filas diga "línea!!" una sola vez y no siempre que haga el bucle...