# creando un bingo con javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy creando un juego de bingo, donde los jugadores tienen una seccion donde poder elegir sus cartones para jugar, pero estoy teniendo un problema al querer generar esos cartones, una serie tiene 6 cartones, en cada carton hay 12 espacios y 15 numeros, y me estoy enredando con muchos numeros necesito una ayuda por favor, les dejo lo que hice hasta el momento

```
function espacios(): Number[] {
  var resultEspacios = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    resultEspacios.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 + 1))
  }
  return resultEspacios
}
```

//en esa funcion genere los 12 espacios

```
function cartones() {

  var carton1 = []
  var carton2 = []
  var carton3 = []
  var carton4 = []
  var carton5 = []
  var carton6 = []

  for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    carton1.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 99 + 1))
  }
  return [carton1, carton2, carton3, carton4, carton5, carton6] 
}
```

en esta funcion lo que quiero hacer es ir generando los numeros de los cartones, el problema que tengo aca es que al querer ingresar solo 15 numeros para cada array ese ciclo for me genera varios numeros de cierto casillero, ejemplo: (dependiendo de los espacios que genere, me tiene que devolver un numero o dos pero este me devuelve mas, ej: 25, 29, 27, 24) lo que yo quiero es que solamente de devuelva uno odos de cada decimal, me explico?

//Aquiero agregar que esto al tenerlo terminado, lo guardo en la bd para poder hacer un seguimiento de si el carton esta adquirido o no, lo que quiero guardar es simplemente un array con esos cartones

un ejemplo con imagen es esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando hablo de `serie`, a lo que me refiero son estos 6 cartones, lo que yo busco es poder generarlo y asi guardarlo en la bd para despues poder monitorear quien lo adquirio para poder avisar/darlo por ganado si es que gana

Comment: Lo siento pero me he perdido intentando seguir tu explicación. Sólo sé que tienes un método que te genera 12 números (que son siempre 1 o 2) y un segundo método que crea una matriz con un array de 15 números aleatorios (que se pueden repetir) y 5 arrays más vacíos

Comment: Relacionado: [Creación de un cartón de bingo con espacios en negro y números aleatorios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/244169/creación-de-un-cartón-de-bingo-con-espacios-en-negro-y-números-aleatorios/244310#244310)

Comment: no es relacionado, antes de publicar mi pregunta busque informacion y esa pregunta no me sirvio por que lo que yo busco es generar un componente para guardarlo en bd, y esa pregunta no es lo que buscaba, por ese motive decidi generar una pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta que en el *BINGO* los números se muestran por columnas y no deben repetirse, además, cada columna debe contener solo ciertos números:

> B: 1 a 15
> I: 16 a 30
> N: 31 a 45
> G: 46 a 60
> O: 61 a 75

No explicaste exactamente cómo es que armas los cartones, así que me basé en el *BINGO* original y solo tienes que adaptar de acuerdo a tus necesidades:

```js
function getBingoCard() {
    // Crear arreglo con subarreglo para cada columna necesaria
    let arr = [
        [], // b (1-15)
        [], // i (16-30)
        [], // n (31-45)
        [], // g (46-60)
        []  // o (51-75)
    ];
    // Llenar cada subarreglo
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // Asignar máximo y mínimo de acuerdo a posición
        let min = (i * 15) + 1;
        let max = min + 15;
        // Este ciclo termina cuando el subarreglo tenga 5 elementos
        while(arr[i].length < 5) {
            let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
            // Evitar que se repitan números
            if(!arr[i].includes(num)) {
                arr[i].push(num);
            }
        }
        // Ordenar
        arr[i].sort((a,b) => a - b);
    }
    // Generalmente el número del centro es un comodín
    arr[2][2] = 'X';
    return arr;
}

function cartones() {
   return [
       getBingoCard(),
       getBingoCard(),
       getBingoCard(),
       getBingoCard(),
       getBingoCard(),
       getBingoCard()
   ] 
}

let cards = cartones();
let html = '';
cards.forEach(card => {
    html += `
      <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>I</th>
        <th>N</th>
        <th>G</th>
        <th>O</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>`;
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        html += `
      <tr>
        <td>${card[0][i]}</td>
        <td>${card[1][i]}</td>
        <td>${card[2][i]}</td>
        <td>${card[3][i]}</td>
        <td>${card[4][i]}</td>
      </tr>
        `;
    }
    html += '</tbody></table>';
});
document.querySelector('#bingo-cards').innerHTML = html;

// Si quieres que se muestren como arreglo, sin subarreglos:
let newCards = [];
for(let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  // Crear arreglo para tarjeta
  let simple = [];
  for(x = 0; x < 5; x ++) {
    simple.push(...cards[i][x]);
  }
  newCards.push(simple);
}
console.log(newCards);
```

```css
table {
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
}
table td {
  border:1px #aaa solid;
  margin:1px;
  padding:3px 5px;
  text-align:center;
}
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3) {
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="bingo-cards"></div>
```

Comment: Me da la impresión de que has leído el titular y has montado todo esto. Que está muy bien montado, y es posible que sea lo que quiera el OP, pero de la pregunta a la respuesta noto que no hay mucha conexión

Comment: @PabloLozano, sí leí todo, por eso mencioné: _No explicaste exactamente cómo es que armas los cartones, así que me basé en el BINGO original y solo tienes que adaptar de acuerdo a tus necesidades_. A fin de cuentas, no es la solución exacta, pero sí la base para llegar a lo que AP busca.

Comment: los cartones que quiero formar estan conformados de la siguiente manera: una serie, contiene 6 cartones, cada carton tiene 12 espacios y 15 numeros, en cada columna varian los espacios, 1 espacio o 2, si en una columna tengo 2 espacios entonces en esa columna tengo 1 numero, si tengo 1 espacio entonces tengo 2 numeros, en cada carton tengo 9  columnas, en cada columna comenzando de izquierda a derecha, en la 1 columna van los numeros del 1 al 9, en la segunda columna del 10 al 19, etc, obviamente, no se deben repetir los numeros en diferentes cartones, juntando los 6 cartones se forma la serie

Comment: @Enzo, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar esa información, junto con un ejemplo de cómo deberían quedar los 6 cartones, no importa si esto último es en imagen.

Comment: ok, ya lo estoy agregando

Comment: ya lo edite y deje un ejemplo con imagen